# python search nested dictionary for value and key

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I have this tuple with nested dictionaries:

`Orders = ({'ret_code': 0, 'ret_msg': 'OK', 'ext_code': '', 'ext_info': '', 'result': [{'user_id': 121212, 'stop_order_id': 'ssdf3215641d215415d', 'symbol': 'XRPUSDT', 'side': 'Sell', 'order_type': 'Market', 'price': 0, 'qty': 2, 'time_in_force': 'ImmediateOrCancel', 'order_status': 'Untriggered', 'trigger_price': 0.8839, 'base_price': '0.8860', 'order_link_id': '', 'created_time': '2021-06-14T14:21:50.000Z', 'updated_time': '2021-06-14T14:21:50.000Z', 'take_profit': 0, 'stop_loss': 0, 'tp_trigger_by': 'UNKNOWN', 'sl_trigger_by': 'UNKNOWN', 'trigger_by': 'LastPrice', 'reduce_only': False, 'close_on_trigger': False}, {'user_id': 121212, 'stop_order_id': 's65d4654sd234165sd4', 'symbol': 'XRPUSDT', 'side': 'Buy', 'order_type': 'Market', 'price': 0, 'qty': 2, 'time_in_force': 'ImmediateOrCancel', 'order_status': 'Untriggered', 'trigger_price': 0.8929, 'base_price': '0.8820', 'order_link_id': '', 'created_time': '2021-06-14T14:03:20.000Z', 'updated_time': '2021-06-14T14:18:59.000Z', 'take_profit': 0, 'stop_loss': 0, 'tp_trigger_by': 'UNKNOWN', 'sl_trigger_by': 'UNKNOWN', 'trigger_by': 'LastPrice', 'reduce_only': True, 'close_on_trigger': True}, {'user_id': 121212, 'stop_order_id': 'sd654s6d5465416ds546s5d4', 'symbol': 'XRPUSDT', 'side': 'Sell', 'order_type': 'Market', 'price': 0, 'qty': 3, 'time_in_force': 'ImmediateOrCancel', 'order_status': 'Untriggered', 'trigger_price': 0.88, 'base_price': '0.8817', 'order_link_id': '', 'created_time': '2021-06-14T14:03:04.000Z', 'updated_time': '2021-06-14T14:18:59.000Z', 'take_profit': 0, 'stop_loss': 0, 'tp_trigger_by': 'UNKNOWN', 'sl_trigger_by': 'UNKNOWN', 'trigger_by': 'LastPrice', 'reduce_only': True, 'close_on_trigger': True}, {'user_id': 121212, 'stop_order_id': 's65d46s5d46s5d46s5d46sd5', 'symbol': 'XRPUSDT', 'side': 'Buy', 'order_type': 'Market', 'price': 0, 'qty': 2, 'time_in_force': 'ImmediateOrCancel', 'order_status': 'Untriggered', 'trigger_price': 0.88, 'base_price': '0.8839', 'order_link_id': '', 'created_time': '2021-06-14T13:58:30.000Z', 'updated_time': '2021-06-14T14:18:59.000Z', 'take_profit': 0, 'stop_loss': 0, 'tp_trigger_by': 'UNKNOWN', 'sl_trigger_by': 'UNKNOWN', 'trigger_by': 'LastPrice', 'reduce_only': True, 'close_on_trigger': True}, {'user_id': 121212, 'stop_order_id': 'sd654s6d54s6d51s6d54s65d4', 'symbol': 'XRPUSDT', 'side': 'Sell', 'order_type': 'Market', 'price': 0, 'qty': 3, 'time_in_force': 'ImmediateOrCancel', 'order_status': 'Untriggered', 'trigger_price': 0.8929, 'base_price': '0.8855', 'order_link_id': '', 'created_time': '2021-06-14T13:49:20.000Z', 'updated_time': '2021-06-14T14:18:59.000Z', 'take_profit': 0, 'stop_loss': 0, 'tp_trigger_by': 'UNKNOWN', 'sl_trigger_by': 'UNKNOWN', 'trigger_by': 'LastPrice', 'reduce_only': True, 'close_on_trigger': True}], 'time_now': '1623682473.336069', 'rate_limit_status': 598, 'rate_limit_reset_ms': 1623682473333, 'rate_limit': 600}, <bravado.requests_client.RequestsResponseAdapter object at 0x00789C86BBFA0>)`

I want to search every dictionary for:

```
'reduce_only': False, 'close_on_trigger': False
```

If available print (True) and get the 'side' for exactly this dictionary:

```
True
Sell
```

The problem is that the dictionary changes depending on the orders
It means that there can be two or three dictionaries in the list
I tried to use For Loop but it only prints variables and keys

```
for x in Orders:
    for y in x:
        print(x)
```

Comment: Hello? Can you add what have you tried so far?

Comment: What is <bravado.requests_client.RequestsResponseAdapter object at 0x00789C86BBFA0>?

Answer (score 2):

Your data doesn't look like a proper Python data.

As for the dictionaries, I see no problem:

```
orders = ({
    'ret_code': 0,
    'ret_msg': 'OK',
    'ext_code': '',
    'ext_info': '',
    'result': [{
            'user_id': 121212,
            'stop_order_id': 'ssdf3215641d215415d',
            'symbol': 'XRPUSDT',
            'side': 'Sell',
            'order_type': 'Market',
            'price': 0,
            'qty': 2,
            'time_in_force': 'ImmediateOrCancel',
            'order_status': 'Untriggered',
            'trigger_price': 0.8839,
            'base_price': '0.8860',
            'order_link_id': '',
            'created_time': '2021-06-14T14: 21: 50.000Z',
            'updated_time': '2021-06-14T14: 21: 50.000Z',
            'take_profit': 0,
            'stop_loss': 0,
            'tp_trigger_by': 'UNKNOWN',
            'sl_trigger_by': 'UNKNOWN',
            'trigger_by': 'LastPrice',
            'reduce_only': False,
            'close_on_trigger': False
        },
        {
            'user_id': 121212,
            'stop_order_id': 's65d4654sd234165sd4',
            'symbol': 'XRPUSDT',
            'side': 'Buy',
            'order_type': 'Market',
            'price': 0,
            'qty': 2,
            'time_in_force': 'ImmediateOrCancel',
            'order_status': 'Untriggered',
            'trigger_price': 0.8929,
            'base_price': '0.8820',
            'order_link_id': '',
            'created_time': '2021-06-14T14: 03: 20.000Z',
            'updated_time': '2021-06-14T14: 18: 59.000Z',
            'take_profit': 0,
            'stop_loss': 0,
            'tp_trigger_by': 'UNKNOWN',
            'sl_trigger_by': 'UNKNOWN',
            'trigger_by': 'LastPrice',
            'reduce_only': True,
            'close_on_trigger': True
        },
        {
            'user_id': 121212,
            'stop_order_id': 'sd654s6d5465416ds546s5d4',
            'symbol': 'XRPUSDT',
            'side': 'Sell',
            'order_type': 'Market',
            'price': 0,
            'qty': 3,
            'time_in_force': 'ImmediateOrCancel',
            'order_status': 'Untriggered',
            'trigger_price': 0.88,
            'base_price': '0.8817',
            'order_link_id': '',
            'created_time': '2021-06-14T14: 03: 04.000Z',
            'updated_time': '2021-06-14T14: 18: 59.000Z',
            'take_profit': 0,
            'stop_loss': 0,
            'tp_trigger_by': 'UNKNOWN',
            'sl_trigger_by': 'UNKNOWN',
            'trigger_by': 'LastPrice',
            'reduce_only': True,
            'close_on_trigger': True
        },
        {
            'user_id': 121212,
            'stop_order_id': 's65d46s5d46s5d46s5d46sd5',
            'symbol': 'XRPUSDT',
            'side': 'Buy',
            'order_type': 'Market',
            'price': 0,
            'qty': 2,
            'time_in_force': 'ImmediateOrCancel',
            'order_status': 'Untriggered',
            'trigger_price': 0.88,
            'base_price': '0.8839',
            'order_link_id': '',
            'created_time': '2021-06-14T13: 58: 30.000Z',
            'updated_time': '2021-06-14T14: 18: 59.000Z',
            'take_profit': 0,
            'stop_loss': 0,
            'tp_trigger_by': 'UNKNOWN',
            'sl_trigger_by': 'UNKNOWN',
            'trigger_by': 'LastPrice',
            'reduce_only': True,
            'close_on_trigger': True
        },
        {
            'user_id': 121212,
            'stop_order_id': 'sd654s6d54s6d51s6d54s65d4',
            'symbol': 'XRPUSDT',
            'side': 'Sell',
            'order_type': 'Market',
            'price': 0,
            'qty': 3,
            'time_in_force': 'ImmediateOrCancel',
            'order_status': 'Untriggered',
            'trigger_price': 0.8929,
            'base_price': '0.8855',
            'order_link_id': '',
            'created_time': '2021-06-14T13: 49: 20.000Z',
            'updated_time': '2021-06-14T14: 18: 59.000Z',
            'take_profit': 0,
            'stop_loss': 0,
            'tp_trigger_by': 'UNKNOWN',
            'sl_trigger_by': 'UNKNOWN',
            'trigger_by': 'LastPrice',
            'reduce_only': True,
            'close_on_trigger': True
        }
    ],
    'time_now': '1623682473.336069',
    'rate_limit_status': 598,
    'rate_limit_reset_ms': 1623682473333,
    'rate_limit': 600
}, '<bravado.requests_client.RequestsResponseAdapter object at 0x00789C86BBFA0 >')

dicts = orders[0]['result']

for i, d in enumerate(dicts):
    reduce = d['reduce_only']
    close  = d['close_on_trigger']
    sell   = d['side']
    try:
        prnt = d['print']
    except:
        prnt = ""

    print(f'dict {i} : {reduce=} {close=} {sell=} {prnt=}')
```

Output:

```
dict 0 : reduce=False close=False sell='Sell' prnt=''
dict 1 : reduce=True close=True sell='Buy' prnt=''
dict 2 : reduce=True close=True sell='Sell' prnt=''
dict 3 : reduce=True close=True sell='Buy' prnt=''
dict 4 : reduce=True close=True sell='Sell' prnt=''
```